# Display R2 in GEE chart

Tags: google-earth-engine, regression, scatterplot

I have created scatter plot in GEE but for some reason it doesn't  display the R2 and the way the linear regression displayd is also not good:

[image]

as you can see. the R2 isn't displayed at all and the linear regression has NDVI inside it.

This is the code I have used:

```
// Generate chart from sample
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(sample, 'SAR', 'NDVI')
    .setChartType('ScatterChart')
    .setOptions({title: "NDVI vs SAR(db)", pointSize: 3,
    legend: {maxLines: 5, position: 'top'},
    series: {
          0: {targetAxisIndex: 0},
          1: {targetAxisIndex: 1}
        },
        vAxes: {
          // Adds titles to each axis.
          0: {title: 'NDVI'},
          1: {title: 'NDVI '}
        },
                hAxes: {
          // Adds titles to each axis.
          0: {title: 'db'},
          1: {title: 'db '}
        },
    trendlines: {
        0: {
          type: 'linear',
          color: 'lightblue',
          lineWidth: 3,
          opacity: 0.7,
          showR2: true,
          visibleInLegend: true
        },

      },
});
```

As you can see, the showR2 is true, what is the mistake?

Answer (score 2):

The R2 value is not shown on the chart by default (I don't know if there is a way to change this behaviour).

It is displayed if you hover the mouse over the legend field for the line, on the displayed chart, or click on that same section.

Here is an example, using different code (R2 section highlighted in red):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In fact, it is shown. it is enough that change position of legend to right.